# Wordpress error no Jquery no admin-ajax.php [500]

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou desenvolvendo um delivery no Wordpress o adicionar itens ao carrinho estava funcionando normal quando tava sem localhost , após subir o delivery pra teste ele parou de funcionar ,
Estou com o seguinte log de erro no console.

```
jquery-1.12.4-wp.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4 POST https://servedelivery.com.br/servedelivery-5.6/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Pela a descrição, esse aconteceu quando você mudou o projeto para localhost, o AJAX está enviando a requisição para o site antigo, você precisa mudar url de action do ajax e apontar para a nova rota.

Eu recomendo deixar a url dinâmica para não der problema nas migrações, por exemplo:

```
 * Adiciona um script no footer que vai inserir uma variável js com uma URL
 * que será utilizada para requisições AJAX
 */
function _theme_load_ajax()
{
    $script = '<script>';
    $script .= 'let ajaxUrl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";';
    $script .= '</script>';

    echo $script;
}
add_action('wp_footer', '_theme_load_ajax');
```

Chame a variavel `ajaxurl` na rota do ajax